# Windows batch file to check for a directory before application launch

Tags: windows, batch-file

How can I check if an NTFS drive exists before launching an application. If it's not present I'd like to display an error message. This is what I've got, but I'm no good at scripting.

**itunes.bat**

```
IF EXIST g:\
START "C:\Program Files (x86)\itunes" itunes.exe
ELSE
cscript MessageBox.vbs "Plug in the HDD"
```

**MessageBox.vbs**

```
Set objArgs = WScript.Arguments
messageText = objArgs(0)
MsgBox messageText
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would try the following:

```
cd g:\
if errorlevel 1 goto fail
START "C:\Program Files (x86)\itunes" itunes.exe
exit

:fail
cscript MessageBox.vbs "Plug in the HDD"
```

Comment: Perhaps improved with PUSHD instead of CD, followed by POPD after error check.

Answer (score 2):

Some drives that support removable media will pop up an error message in a window if you attempt to access them when they are not ready. You can eliminate the Windowed error message and take control of the discovery process if you use the VOL command.

```
2>nul vol g: && (
  START "C:\Program Files (x86)\itunes" itunes.exe
) || (
  cscript MessageBox.vbs "Plug in the HDD"
)
```